# Why doesn't my function call match this generic functions implementation?

Tags: c++, templates

It seems like the compiler is very close to doing what I want (because it calls out my function as a candidate), but I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

template <class U, template<class U> class T>
void AppendSorted( T<U>& l, U val )
{
  typename T<U>::reverse_iterator rt = l.rbegin();

  while( ((*rt) > val) && (rt != l.rend()) )
    rt++;

  l.insert( rt.base(), val );
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    list<int> foo;
    AppendSorted<int, list<int> >( foo, 5 );

    list<int>::iterator i;
    for( i = foo.begin(); i != foo.end(); i++ )
    {
        printf("%d\n",*i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
test.cpp:21:43: error: no matching function for call to ‘AppendSorted(std::list<int>&, int)’
test.cpp:21:43: note: candidate is:
test.cpp:8:6: note: template<class U, template<class U> class T> void AppendSorted(T<U>&, U)
```

Comment: you will abbend on the initial insert in your AppendSorted, btw, because the eval order for your while() clause is going to dereference iterator pointing at rend() when the list is empty. reverse the expressions in the while() condition to avoid this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This signature

```
template <class U, template<class U> class T>
void AppendSorted( T<U>& l, U val )
```

indicates that there will be one concrete type (`class U`) and one template (`template<class U> class T`).

This invocation

```
AppendSorted<int, list<int> >( foo, 5 );
```

provides two concrete types, `int` and `list<int>`.  `list` is a template, `list<int>` is a concrete type, a template instance, but not a template.

Just change the function to accept the concrete type of the collection:

```
template <class U, class T>
void AppendSorted( T& l, U val )
{
  typename T::reverse_iterator /* or auto */ rt = l.rbegin();

  while( (rt != l.rend()) && ((*rt) > val) )
    rt++;

  l.insert( rt.base(), val );
}
```

And let the compiler infer the type arguments, instead of specifying them.

```
AppendSorted( foo, 5 );
```

Comment: Changing the function call to: AppendSorted<int,list>( foo, 5 ); results in the same error.

Comment: I can't use C++11 for this (unfortunately) so "auto" is out. When I declare rt as: T<U>::reverse_iterator (with you're template specification) I get "'T' is not a template" which is what forced me to use the template specification I had originally.

Comment: @dicroce: Just `T::reverse_iterator`.  `T` isn't a template, it's `list<int>`.  And `list<int>::reverse_iterator` makes good sense, while `list<int><int>::reverse_iterator` doesn't.

Comment: Ok 'typename T::reverse_iterator' got it :)

Answer (score 2):

`std::list` is template taking two parameters - not only one. There is second default parameter.

You would need such template function to match list:

```
template <class U, template<class U,class A> class T>
void AppendSorted( T<U,std::allocator<T>>& l, U val );
```

But what about `std::set` - it requires 3 parameters?

I am not sure - maybe variadic templates would help...

But just try this:

```
template <class U, class Container>
void AppendSorted(  Container& l, U val);
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::list` have actually two template parameters:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

template <class U, template<class> class AL, template<class,class> class T> 
void AppendSorted( T<U,AL<U>>& l, U val ) {
        typename T<U,AL<U>>::reverse_iterator rt = l.rbegin();

        while( ((*rt) > val) && (rt != l.rend()) )
                rt++;

        l.insert( rt.base(), val );
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
        list<int> foo;
        AppendSorted( foo, 5 ); 

        list<int>::iterator i; 
        for( i = foo.begin(); i != foo.end(); i++ ) {
                printf("%d\n",*i);
        }  

        return 0; 
}
```

Now it will compile, but you have logic error in your code - you have past-the-end iterator.  To fix that, in you while loop, check for `rend()` first:

```
    while(rt != l.rend()  &&  *rt > val)
```